# django 1.6 with django_tables2 cannot change DATETIME_FORMAT

Tags: django, datetime, python-2.7, django-tables2

python 2.7.5+. django_tables2 0.14.0

In settings.py:

```
USE_L10N = True
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'M j, Y H:i:s.u'
```

Didn't work.  I tried `{% load L10N %}` at the top of my template.  Didn't work.

I created a formats directory at the top of my project containing an en directory containing formats.py and added the following to my settings.py (yes, there are **init**.py files in the formats directory and in the en directory):

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = '<project>.formats'
```

Didn't work.

I tried putting in `{{created_at|date: 'M j, Y'}}{{created_at|time: 'H:i:s.u'}}` before the `{% render_table table %}` tag from django_tables2.  Got an error.

Tried the recommended django_tables2 method of, in my tables.py definition, adding to the Meta class:

```
localize('created_at')
```

Didn't work.

Tried putting 'localize=True' in the column definition for created_at in tables.py.

Didn't work.

The only thing that worked was modifying python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale/en/formats.py (in my virtual environment) but I won't be allowed to do that on my project because it's not considered portable.

I see stackoverflow entries that say this works but they are many years old and many django versions back. I see others here that say this doesn't work and they haven't/aren't going to fix it.

This functionality logs requests; during testing the other devs could really use seeing seconds and probably microseconds to help them debug but I can't seem to give it to them.

Any suggestions that I haven't already tried?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, *blush* - I got it. I made the following change in the model for the DateTimeField created_at:

```
@property
    def nice_date(self):
        # mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.uuuuuu
        t = self.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
        return t
```

Then, I displayed nice_date instead of created_at.

I hope this helps someone else.